# Problem with polygon overlay in raster stats using gdal

Tags: python, raster, gdal, overlay, zonal-statistics

I am using the raster_stats module in python to calculate the mean carbon value for different sets of polygons. Here is the code that I am using:

```
africa_sat = 'E:/Research_Work/data/processing_data/carbon_satcchi/data/raw_data/africa_carbon_1km.tif'
name_clipshp = 'data/grid_clipped/' + name_hol + '_grid_cl.shp' # create object to point to clipped grid file

africa_stats = raster_stats(name_clipshp, africa_sat,stats=['mean'])
```

I have approximately 260 grid surface areas that I am employing. The grid areas have between ~10,000 polygons and ~40,000 polygons in them. Here is the error message I get for some of grids:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\main.py", line 153, in raster_stats
 rvds.SetGeoTransform(new_gt)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'
```

I do not get this error message, if the polygon overlaps completely with the raster image (tiff file) or if the polygon does not at all overlap with the polygon. However, if only a part of the polygon overlaps with the raster I get the error that is above. See picture below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to force gdal to create null / NA value in the polygons that don't overlap? Does anyone know a create solution to this issue?

Comment: Really late to the party, but are you using exceptions: gdal.UseExceptions()
ogr.UseExceptions()